# Let $f \colon \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be a complex valued function given by $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y).$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following question :

[image]

### MY ATTEMPT:

By Cauchy Riemann equation ,we have $u_x=v_y,u_y=-v_x.$ Now $v(x,y)=3xy^2 \implies v_x=3y^2 \implies -u_y=3y^2 \implies u=-y^3+ \phi(x) $. Now,I am not sure which way to go? Can someone give some explanation about which way to go in order to pick the correct option?

Comment: HINT: the imaginary part of any holomorphic function must be harmonic.

Comment: Now compute $u_x$ based on the $u$ you have and set it equal to $v_y=6xy$. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function is holomorphic, than $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ must be harmonically adjoint. That means, that $v(x,y)$ must satisfy 
$$\Delta v(x,y)=0; $$

We found the values of $\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}$

$$\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}=0; \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}=6x $$

So, the next equality must be true for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}$

$$6x=0 $$

But this is true only for $x=0.$ So, this function can not be holomorphic for any $u(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you used the second C.R. equation arriving at $u(x,y)=-y^3+\phi(x)$. What does it happen if you apply the other C.R. equation, i.e. $u_x=v_y$, to your result?

Comment: By using other C-R equ,we get , $u=3x^2y+\phi(y)$. So I think option 1 is the correct choice. Am I right?

Comment: I mean, you have $u=-y^3+\phi(x)$, now. Put it into $u_x=v_y$ and check what does it happen, in particular, to $\phi(x)...$

Comment: It gives me $u_x=\phi'(x), v_y=6xy.$ Now $u_x=v_y $ gives $\phi(x)=3x^2y+A,$where A is constant. I am still not sure how to make conclusion from it. can you add some details in your answer?

Comment: $u_x=v_y$ gives you $\phi'(x)=6xy$. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it is not possible as it contains the term $y$ on the right hand side of the expression.Am i right?

Comment: exactly :-). You are done.